# MySQL - if EXISTS returns true, shouldn't the outer query results be no more filtered

Tags: mysql, where-clause, exists, correlated-subquery

I am quoting from [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/) :

"You can use the query above as a correlated subquery to find customers who placed at least one sales order with the total value greater than 60K by using the EXISTS operator:

```
SELECT 
    customerNumber, 
    customerName
FROM
    customers
WHERE
    EXISTS( SELECT 
            orderNumber, SUM(priceEach * quantityOrdered)
        FROM
            orderdetails
                INNER JOIN
            orders USING (orderNumber)
        WHERE
            customerNumber = customers.customerNumber
        GROUP BY orderNumber
        HAVING SUM(priceEach * quantityOrdered) > 60000);
```

"
You can paste the code in the editor [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/tryit/) to see the results.

Suppose I omit the `WHERE` clause in the subquery and the `EXISTS` operator returns `TRUE`. 1) Then why can't I  get the `customerNumber` and `customerName` of all the customers ? 2) How many times is the `EXISTS` operator evaluated ?

Comment: 1) Doesen't "SELECT 
    customerNumber, 
    customerName
FROM
    customers" work? It should. That would be the query, if EXISTS returned TRUE.

Comment: What is the answer to the question no. 1 ?

Comment: 1) If you ommit where in the subquery you will get all customers from customers table only if total value for all customers is > 60k in orders table, i.e. if your subquery returns at least one row on its own.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) If you remove `where` clause from subquery, it is giving all customername and customernumbers because currently you've at least 1 order who qualifies the following condition:

```
HAVING SUM(priceEach * quantityOrdered) > 60000)
```

Hence, the subquery will always return `True`.

But when there are no orders that qualifies the above condition, it won't display anything as subquery will always return `False`.

As for now, subquery returns true and displaying all customers. You can verify that as follows:

```
SELECT 
    count(*)
FROM
    customers
WHERE
    EXISTS( SELECT 
            orderNumber, SUM(priceEach * quantityOrdered)
        FROM
            orderdetails
                INNER JOIN
            orders USING (orderNumber)       
        GROUP BY orderNumber
        HAVING SUM(priceEach * quantityOrdered) > 60000);
```

**Result:**

```
count(*)
---------
122
```

Now, run this query:

```
Select count(*) from customers;
```

**Result:**

```
count(*)
---------
122
```

Now, both returns same amount of rows hence you can tell that it subquery returns true for all customers.

2) I don't think there is a definite or exact answer for that. Normally, Query planner/Query optimizer transform co-related subqueries with `EXISTS` into `Join` and hence they executed only once.

For more info, [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800008/number-of-times-a-nested-query-is-executed)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your answer is wrong. Or rather imprecise. And your "proof" is kind of poor. Just because by coincidence the right result is returned, doesn't mean it's always right.

Comment: It's not coincidence. I checked subquery without where clause and it returns rows(3 rows to be precise). It means, it'll return true for each and every customer and hence return all the customers. What's wrong in this logic.

Comment: I went for `count(*)` because customernumber are not sequential. Hence, that's the only way to compare the results.

Comment: Yes, now that you've basically copied my answer it is right.

Comment: Copy? I already explain the added points to you in comments above. I just forgot to add that in my answer. Thanx for pointing that out. But copy?? No way.

Comment: Thank you for mark it as answer. Fell free to ask doubts if you've any.

Answer (score 1):

When you remove the `WHERE` clause in your subquery, you will only get all customerNumbers and -names, if there's any orderNumber where priceEach * quantityOrdered > 60000. If there's not, no row will be returned.

Regarding your second question, I'm not sure what you mean. The specialty of `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT whatever FROM foo` is, that EXISTS opposed to `WHERE x IN (SELECT y FROM foo)` stops as soon as the subquery returns a boolean true or a value other than `0`. The `IN (<subquery>)` doesn't stop after the first hit. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: `EXISTS opposed to WHERE x IN (SELECT y FROM foo) stops as soon as the subquery returns a boolean true or a value` - if that is so, then when I do not omit the `WHERE` clause from the sub query why doesn't the result show all the customers ?

Comment: Because not for every customerNumber a result is returned. You have a bunch of customerNumbers from the outer query. Each customerNumber is used in a separate execution of the subquery. Then there are following possibilities. 1) There is no entry in the orderDetails table with a customerNumber from the outer query. No result is returned, the outer query doesn't print a customerName to your terminal. 2) There is a customerNumber with an entry in orderDetail, but there is no order with a value over 60000. No result is returned from the subquery, no customerName from the outer query is returned.

Comment: 3) There is a customerNumber with an orderDetail entry with value over 60000. Then it actually doesn't matter what you select in the subquery, as long as it's not false or 0. You can for example simply `select 1 from orderDetails...having...`. So when the subquery returns a true or non-0 result, the outer query returns this customerName.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed So, did I explain good enough? Any more questions?